# On scroll up change the tableview header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When the user scrolls upwards the tableview header GUI is changed. Can someone suggest any library in swift?.

Comment: **Check this one maybe it will help you** https://github.com/romansorochak/ParallaxHeader

Comment: Thanks @NikunjKumbhani

Comment: Most Welcome :)